# How to fix Doxygen warning for a deprecated enum?

Tags: c++, qt, doxygen

I have an enum declared as follows:

```
/**
  * Classification mode
  * \deprecated since QGIS 3.10 use QgsClassificationMethod::MethodId instead
  */
enum Q_DECL_DEPRECATED Mode
{
  EqualInterval,
  Quantile,
  Jenks,
  StdDev,
  Pretty,
  Custom
};
```

When I build the API docs with Doxygen (1.8.11 or 1.8.13, did not try more recent), here is the warning I have:

```
warning: no uniquely matching class member found for 
  enum Q_DECL_DEPRECATED QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer::QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer::Mode()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you enable preprocessing for Doxygen? Do you include Qt header?

Comment: I'm not able to directly reproduce the problem (as I don't have the settings you changed from the default doxygen configuration file and also not the call that gives the warning). Maybe you have to have a look at http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html and define Q_DECL_DEPRECATED. As a side not what does the `/!` do in your code (probably something from a copy / paste)

Comment: Yes, preprocessing enabled, I tried to include <QObject> without succcess.

Comment: @albert you would add Q_DECL_DEPRECATED to the PREDEFINED list?

Comment: That might be a possible solution but I cannot say for certain as I don't have asmall MWE that shows the problem.